# Add route after connecting to Windows L2TP VPN

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, routing

I have a basic TP-Link router that has a VPN server built into it at home. I have set up the L2TP VPN server and successfully connected to it with my Windows 10 client. I only want to route traffic over the VPN that is destined for the remote network, so I have unticked the 'Use default gateway on remote network' tickbox and added a route to the remote network manually using the 'route add' command in CMD. After doing this I am able to communicate with devices on that network.

My question is, how can I set this up to automatically add the route after connecting to the VPN? Since the VPN client IP changes dynamically the route may not always be the same. I've seen people posting about being able to do this with a batch script, but haven't been able to find any clear examples.

Is anyone able to advise how best to do this?

Comment: Hi, please check whether it's helpful to you: https://serverfault.com/questions/178181/can-i-automatically-route-add-xxxx-after-i-make-a-vpn-connection-in-windows-7

Comment: I can create a bat file to connect to the VPN just fine, but that article doesn't help me setting the route correctly based on the dynamically assigned IP address of the VPN interface. For example, one time I connect the VPN IP could be 192.168.1.1 and another time it could be 192.168.1.4. Unless I'm missing something?